# Qgis 3.16 - layer can not projected

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis-3

I have a point layer (EPSG:27572) and I'd like to reproject in PyQgis/Toolbox to EPSG:3857. Under 3.14 version, everything's ok.

Then I update to Qgis 3.16 and it doesn't work correctly. Only 3/20 points are reprojected, the other 17 disappear in the new layer.

In the, log I have this:

> Feature could not be written to
> Reprojeté_3adb92c6_1696_40c8_98cb_9bed5e7a55a2: Impossible
> d'enregistrer l'attribut "ref_certificate_ids": Impossible de
> convertir la valeur "" vers le type destination

If I divide the layer to 20 layers (1 layer = 1 point), each layer is reprojected correctly. But it's not a nice way to process and I'd like to understand why.

I wonder if there's any change in the algorithm? And how can I do to reproject altogether correctly?

Comment: Can you please post some more details: What does your code look like? What is the type of the attribute **ref_certificate_ids** and what values are in it? Right off hand, I have no idea what the problem could be.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you question. I just figure out the reason but I still can not know why. This column in our database is array type. The three points reprojected have NULL in this column. So I just ignore this column to advance.
sql = "select id, the_geom_pointfrom gen_building where in"+id_liste
uri.setDataSource("", '('+sql+')', "the_geom_point", "","id")

It seems that Qgis 3.16 does not manage the array type column?